# Is there any way to add or remove object dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having one form and will get values from the input. On button click, I am forming one object like below,

```
let data = filter : {
    metadata : {
        name: apple,
        type: fruits
    },
    match_attributes: {
        value : code_1
    }
}
```

Here, I need to remove the object "match_attributes", if "value" key is empty. My expected output will be like below,

```
let data = filter : {
    metadata : {
        name: apple,
        type: fruits
    }
}
```

I tried by something like this but not worked,

```
    let test = {};
            if(this.getValue) {
             test =   match_attributes : {
                    value : this.getValue
                }
            }


filter : {
match_metadata : {
    name: this.name,
    type: this.type
},
test
}
```

My Output :

```
let data = filter : {
        metadata : {
            name: this.fruitName,
            type: this.fruitType
        },
        { }
    }
```

Is there anyway to do this. Cheers.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and make a [mcve]

Comment: What is `this.getValue`

Comment: you mean if your key doenst exist or if the value for the key value is empty?

Comment: To delete a specific key from an object use `delete` -> `delete data.filter.match_attributes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to conditionally add properties to an object is like this:

```
let data = {
    metadata : {
        name: apple,
        type: fruits
    }
}

if (code_1) {
   data.match_attributes = {
      value : code_1
   }
}
```

You can also delete already existing stuff from objects like this:

```
let data = {
    metadata : {
        name: apple,
        type: fruits
    },
   match_attributes: {
      value: code_1
   }
}

if (!data.match_attributes.value) {
   delete data.match_attributes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = 
{
'filter' : {
    'metadata' : {
        'name': 'apple',
        'type': 'fruits'
    },
    'match_attributes': {
        'value' : ''
    }
}
}
if(!data.filter.match_attributes.value){
delete data.filter.match_attributes
}

console.log(data);
```

Yes, you can use delete operator to do that. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could construct the base object first, then add the (match_attributes) object only when it is available:

```
let test = {
  match_metadata : {
    name: this.name,
    type: this.type
  }
}

if(this.getValue) {
  test.match_attributes = {
    value : this.getValue
  }
}
```